# Dynamically instantiate classes which implement an interface and invoke interface method

Tags: java, reflection, interface, invoke

I have an interface, `LogParser`, consisting of a single method `parse(String x)`. I also have an ArrayList containing the names of multiple classes which all implement `LogParser`. Is it possible to loop through this list of class names and dynamically instantiate their respective classes and invoke `parse(String x)`?

The issue I've had is that the classes do not have zero-argument constructors, so I have run into InstantiationException a lot attempting to invoke the parse method through reflection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation types don't have constructors, it will be very painful. The easiest way to do it is probably to use a dependency injection framework like Spring or Guice.

In Spring, you could just inject a `List<LogParser>`, and you would get all known implementations:

```
@Autowired
private List<LogParser> parsers;
```

Now of course you would have to define each of the `LogParser`s separately as Spring bean.

There is similar functionality in other frameworks as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke some constructor to instantiate an object usefully. You use reflection to grab the `Method` for the constructor, and you instantiate with that. See [Instantiate a class object with constructor that accepts a string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3574065/131433). I didn't close as duplicate, since you have the additional question: Do you know that all your classes have a constructor with the same signature?