# How to cast Java class to another class

Tags: java, class, casting

I use a method to collect all classes from a package and save them into an array:

```
Class[] classes = ClassUtils.getClasses("xyz.keahie.werewolf.character.characters");
```

They all have the class "Character" as superclass and when I print them I get this line:

```
class xyz.keahie.werewolf.character.Character
```

When I want to cast them to the class "Character" I always get an ClassCastException. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Here is the full Error which I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to xyz.keahie.werewolf.character.Character
    at xyz.keahie.werewolf.character.CharacterManager.<init>(CharacterManager.java:29)
    at xyz.keahie.werewolf.GameManager.<init>(GameManager.java:26)
    at xyz.keahie.werewolf.Game.main(Game.java:9)
```

And here my source code:

```
Class[] classes = ClassUtils.getClasses("xyz.keahie.werewolf.character.characters");
for (Class clazz : classes) {
    Object object = clazz.getSuperclass();
    System.out.println(object.toString());

    if (object.getClass().equals(xyz.keahie.werewolf.character.Character.class)) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nope");
    }

    Character character = (Character) object;
    if (!this.characters.contains(character)) {
        addSpecialCharacter(character);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the missing information at the begin

Comment: might be you are trying to cast it to the wrong Character class

Comment: Can you paste the full error, I suspect it will show Michaels answer is correct.

Comment: I just added the full error and my source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a `Class<Character>` to `Character`. Your code

```
Character character = (Character) object;
```

should be

```
Class<Character> characterClass = (Class<Character>) object;
```

It looks like you want to create instance from its class. I recommend you to learn something about Java reflection. Maybe something like this [Creating an instance using the class name and calling constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor)

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I know I should learn more about reflections. Your link helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot cast from `Class<Character>` to `Character`. The former describes the *class* of the latter.

You can use `Class.newInstance` to get an instance provided `Character` has a constructor which takes no arguments:

```
Character character = (Character) object.newInstance();
```

Alternatively, you can use reflection if your `Character` class requires constructor arguments. See this question: [Instantiate a class object with constructor that accepts a string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574065/instantiate-a-class-object-with-constructor-that-accepts-a-string-parameter)

I would carefully rethink your software design if need to instantiate an object from it's `Class<?>` because it is very rarely required.

---

Be careful with naming your class `Character`. [`java.lang.Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) may conflict. [`java.lang`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) is always automatically imported so you have two classes with the same name that are conflicting. It's good practice to avoid using any class names that are already present in `java.lang` for that reason.

To avoid this, you can fully qualify the class with the package name, like so:

```
xyz.keahie.werewolf.character.Character
```

Preferably, choose a less ambiguous name for your class. `GameCharacter`, `PlayerCharacter` or `RpgCharacter` might be better choices.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately the imported Character class is the right one. I also get this message with the exception: `java.lang.Class cannot be cast to xyz.keahie.werewolf.character.Character`
So it must be my Character class and not the java.lang.Character class

Comment: @KeanuHie Thanks. I've updated my answer. Hope it's useful.